# Hay alguna forma de hacer esto de una manera correcta, React - Añadir elementos a una BD que vienen desde una API

Tags: reactjs, select, axios, backend

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es, que al momento de que selecciono el usuario y además la Celda, solo quiero que me envié los datos independiente, pero este me esta mandando todos los datos que están en ambos arrays, para cada una de sus selecciones, habría alguna manera de hacer esto de una manera limpia? Me podrías ayudar a ver donde estoy fallando porfavor.

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

```
const Vehicle = () => {
const [placa, setPlaca] = useState("");
const [color, setColor] = useState("");
const [tipo, setTipo] = useState("");
const [idUsuario, setIdUsuario] = useState([]);
const [idCelda, setIdCelda] = useState([]);

// console.log(idCelda);
console.log(idUsuario)

const handleSelect = (e) => {
    const option = e.target.value;
    console.log(option);
}


const gettingUsers = async () => {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:4500/api/v1/usuarios')
        .then(res => {
            const usuarios = res.data.user;
            console.log(usuarios);
            setIdUsuario(usuarios);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

const gettingCeldas = async () => {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:4500/api/v1/celdas').then((response) => {
      const celdas = response.data.celdas;
      console.log(celdas);

      setIdCelda(celdas);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    gettingCeldas();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    gettingUsers();
  }, []);  


const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newVehicle = {
        placa,
        color,
        tipo,
        idUsuario,
        idCelda
    };
    console.log(newVehicle);
    axios.post('http://localhost:4500/api/v1/vehiculos', newVehicle)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));
}




return (
<div>
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit} >
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="new__vehicle"
        placeholder="Placa del vehiculo"
        value={placa}
        onChange={(e) => setPlaca(e.target.value)}
        autoFocus
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="new__vehicle"
        placeholder="Color del vehiculo"
        value={color}
        onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="new__vehicle"
        placeholder="Que tipo de vehiculo es?" 
        value={tipo}
        onChange={(e) => setTipo(e.target.value)}
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <select onClick={handleSelect}>
            <option value="">Seleccionar un usuario</option>
          { idUsuario.map(user => (  <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>{user.nombre}</option>))}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select  onClick={handleSelect}>
          <option value="">Seleccionar una celda</option>
          { idCelda.map(celda => (  <option  key={celda.id} value={celda.celdaNumero}>{celda.celdaNumero}</option>))}
      </select>
    </div>

    <button className="btn__vehicle">
        Agregar Vehiculo
    </button>        
  </form>
</div>
);
};

export default Vehicle;
```

Here I have some photos where it is evident that it is trying to send the whole array, when it should only be a user, because there I am a little confused.

[image: Prueba 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

Answer (score 1):

Una cosa son las opciones del Select y otra el valor que seleccionas.

En `IdCelda` estas guardando todas las opciones posibles, y cuando seleccionas una opción en el `Select` no estas guardando el valor seleccionado en ningun sitio, solo tienes hecho un `OnClick` que muestra por consola el valor:

```
 const handleSelect = (e) => {
    const option = e.target.value;
    console.log(option);
}
```

Por eso luego en `IdCelda` siempre están todas las opciones. Deberías crear otro `useState` para las opciones y `IdCelda` setearlo con el valor seleccionado mediante un `OnChange`

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, seria bueno si me hubieses dejado un ejemplo, de como usar ese onChange aqui en React.

Comment: Porque si le paso el onChange asi! me da un error. onChange={(e) => setIdUsuario(e.target.value)}